# How should I mark a child entity Inactive instead of deleting from the database but have them behave the same?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I am using Code First and have entities like these:

```
public class Account 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When removing a Contact from an Account, I would delete the row from the database. Now instead of deleting the row we update a status column to Inactive. Here I added a Status property to the Contact entity:

```
public class Contact 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ContactStatus Status {g et; set; }
}

public enum ContactStatus 
{
    Active = 0,
    Inactive = 1
}
```

Inactive contacts should behave like ones deleted from the database. The user of the website will go to delete the contact and it will 'disappear' like it did before.

Here is our current solution. We create another property called ActiveContacts:

```
public class Account 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contact> ActiveContacts
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Contacts.Where(c => c.Status == Status.Active).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

There are some issues with this. Business logic and linq queries are not aware of the new Status property. I then search all the code for references to the old property, Contacts. Is there a better solution than changing all the references of Contacts to ActiveContacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best thing that I could come up with. Feel free to point out any pitfalls or gotchas that might occur with this approach.

I renamed the navigation property ContactsCollection and used the InversePropertyAttribute to maintain a reference to the raw collection from the database. A Contacts property now returns a list of Contacts with a Status of Active.

```
public class Account 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Contact")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> ContactsCollection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a list of all Contacts with an Active Status
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts
    { 
        get 
        {
            return ContactsCollection.Where(c => c.Status == Status.Active).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I do not have to search the code base and rename occurrences of Contacts with a property using another name.

I also get compile errors wherever the new get-only Contacts property is attempted to be assigned to or added to. I never assign or add to the collection in a non-compiled razer view. This is working well so far.